# Create Data Relationships with SOAP API

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, dataextensions

Is there a way to create a Data Relationship between Data Extensions using the SOAP API? I haven't found any documentation regarding this topic.

Answer (score 3):

Data Relationships aren't exposed by the SOAP API, or any other API. The list of objects and the methods you can perform with them is [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/supported_operations_for_objects_and_methods.htm).